# View Pdf in android application without downloading (No internet connection)

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to display a PDF in an Android application.

Constraints are: PDF cannot be downloaded to the mobile phone. Server through which PDF is getting downloaded is on Local network.

I can work on any option: getting the PDF to display on webview (more preferable) or getting the PDF to display using native technique. 
Also if any solution involves converting the PDF to HTML and then displaying it will also be acceptable.

Comment: you can search for a PHP PDF displaying library (or other depending on your server) to be able to view PDF in a WebView. This way you don't need any client side libraries

Comment: ok that's great! .. I didn't try this approach will try this..

Answer (score 1):

you can use third party library for this

https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager

it works for me